# All possible columnwise multiplications in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using an input matrix of shape `m * n`, or `m` rows and `n` columns. I wish to compute the element-wise product of all possible combinations of *columns*. Hence I need to output a matrix of shape `m * n*n`.
 More concretely, let's say my input matrix has columns `[c1, c2, c3 ... cn]`. My output matrix should look like `[c1*c1 c1*c2 ... c1*cn c2*c1 c2*c2 ... cn*cn]`, where `ci*cj` is a vector representing the element-wise multiplication of vectors `ci` and `cj`.

I don't want to use a `for` loop, looking for a neat way to do this using `numpy` APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`broacasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending the input array to two `3D` extended versions with singleton dimensions along the second and third ones and then performing element-wise multiplication and a final reshape is needed for a `2D` final output.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
(a[:,:,None]*a[:,None,:]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Put another way, making use of `...` and skipping the last axis after `None` for the second extended version, would be -

```
(a[...,None]*a[:,None]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Another approach with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',a,a).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```